# How do I create an object of an ArrayList <Shape> in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, shapes

I want to create a new object of an `ArrayList` Of `Shape`. The `ArrayList` contains shapes, rectangle, ellipse etc... `ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();`
The new object must contain the shapes that it holds and a text attribute to name the shape. This is what i want to achieve:

How can I do this?

**EDITED**

**Here is what i wanted to say**
[image]

**I've reached here! Now i want java to write it as "Student is linked to ID"**

[image]

Comment: Create interface Shape and implement in different shape classes.

Comment: To store this, i'd add a tex atribute to the class shape, and create an ArrayList as you said

Comment: If you have to combine a Shape and a String (?), write a class containing a Shape and a String, and the List contains objects of that combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class NamedShape {
    private String name;
    private Shape shape;
    public NamedShape( String name, Shape shape ){
        this.name = name;
        this.shape = shape;
    }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public Shape getShape(){ return shape; }
}
```

Now you can create a `List<NamedShape>` etc.

```
List<NamedShape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
shapes.add( new NamedShape( "Humpty-Dumpty",
                            new Ellipse2D.Double( x, y, w, h ) ) );
shapes.add( new NamedShape( "John Doe",
                            new Rectangle2D.Double( u, v, a, b ) ) );
```

Or you iterate over the `List<Shape>` you have and add the name:

```
for( Shape shape: myUnnamedShapes ){
    shapes.add( new NamedShape( inventName(), shape ) );
}
```

**Later** To paint,

```
for (NamedShape s : shapes) { 
    graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next()); 
    graphSettings.draw(s.getShape()); 
}
```

Comment: can you please just tell me if the shapes that are inside this array "shapes" `ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();`  will also be present inside the  `ArrayList<NamedShape> t = new ArrayList<NamedShape>();` if no then how can i use this new array "NamedSpace"? My Shapes are initially saved inside the array "shapes". How it will work with the array "NamedSpace" can you please explain to me?

Comment: Please just clarify this?

Comment: Based On what you posted, Do i have to remove my ArrayList: ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();  ? I will have to edit my whole block of codes if i have to remove this arraylist shape. Is there a way that i can link the array "Shape" to "NamedShape"?

Comment: Can you please tell me how i do this for loop?                                ` for (NamedShape s : shapes) {
 
                
                graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());

                graphSettings.draw(s);

            }` Its giving me error on the last line for the "s"

Comment: Done - see extended answer. NamedShape is just a "parcel" for two objects. Where you had a Shape, you now have a NamedShape, and you have to call getShape() on it to extract the Shape. - You can always extend it, adding more objects.

Comment: Superbe!! You are just great!! now if i want to retrieve data of a specific index for the NamedShape() what do i do? I want to retrieve the "Shape" and the "Name" of a specific index inside the array "NamedShape"?

Comment: Can you please see my edited code above and tell me based on what you've advised me if my arraylist will look like result1 or result2? This will help me to proceed and remove my doubts.

Comment: It'll be more like result #2: one object per (Array)List entry, each NamedShape object contains a reference to a String and one to a Shape. Note that the reference you take from your original `List<Shape>` is the one my snippet inserts into the NamedShape. You can, provided `i` is less than the list's `shapes.size()` use `shapes.get(i)` to retrieve a NamedShape object and apply `getShape()` to that: `shapes.get(0).getShape()` would return the first Shape added to the NamedShape list.

Comment: BTW, did you consider using a `Map<String,Shape>`, which is another way of "associating a (string) name with a Shape"? You kept asking for an ArrayList, so I never mentioned that, and a Map doesn't let you access entries by an index value - you'd need to know the "name".

Comment: Infact, i'm working on a project where i have to convert my Shapes into tables. (ER Diagram to tables). So, i draw my shapes, it sends me a pop up message to name the shape. The shape and its name is saved into that ArrayList <NamedShape> it will then check for collision with other shapes, if there are any collisions it retrieves the name of the shape (based on their index). and it will say "Line 1 is linked to Student" "Line1 is linked to ID" . For now, I've been able to do everything that I described above!

Comment: I'm now at a stage where i have to make java understand that if a line of the same index has a collision with 2 shapes(if line(1) is linked to 2 shapes of different indexes) then eventually "Student" is linked to "ID". Only after that, i will be able to make the conversion.

Comment: Could you provide an example in simple terms I might understand? "line"? "Student"? "ID"? I do know what these *words* mean, but the scenario you describe isn't clear to me.

Comment: Please see the above last picture that I've posted. May be this will help you to better understand.

Comment: What i want is that i gives me "Student is linked to ID"

Comment: The concept of a "line" connecting a "rectangle" (associated with "Student") and an "ellipse" (associated with "ID") is something that isn't expressed with an `ArrayList<NamedShape>`, as this merely collects unconnected Shape objects with some String (the "name") inside. If you need to represent connected Shape objects (named or not), a different data structure may be required. An ArrayList merely collects NamedShapes, i.e., shapes with a String to be displayed inside.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how i can rectify this? I mean what data structure you think will be correct? I've already done more than 75% of the work using ArrayList. For now everything is working fine, i just need to know how i can  get this "Student is linked to ID". If I decide to change the data structure i will have to start everything again :(

Comment: This depends on the way the linkage is defined and entered into the system. It also depends on what can be connected: one shape to one other shape, one shape to several other shapes, some shapes to several other shapes. What is it? 1:1, 1:n, m:n?

Comment: Please see last picture above.

Comment: For now am concentrating on a 1:1 relationship like on  the picture, one shape connected to one other shape.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72272/discussion-between-laune-and-lanam).

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Create an interface `Shape` -

```
interface Shape {

}
```

**2.** Now each of the shape - rectangle, ellipse etc  can implement the `Shape`  interface -

```
Rectangle implements Shape{
 String name;
 // other properties as required

  //constructor as your requirement
  //getters setters as your requirement
}
```

Or -

```
Ellipse implements Shape{
     String name;
     // other properties as required

     //constructor as your requirement
     //getters setters as your requirement

    }
```

**3.** Now create an `ArrayList` of `Shape` -

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>)();
```

Since both `Rectangle` and `Ellipse`  implements `Shape` the `ArrayList` shapes can hold both type of object. After that you can write -

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
shapes.add(r);
shapes.add(e);
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.